# How to programmatically create a firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a firebase project with a firestore instance programatically. I've been using the `firebase-tools` cli and have managed to create a new project, a web app and get the app config, but I still need to manually enter the console and click the "Create database" button. Is it possible to automate this process?

Comment: There is presently no public API for creating a Firestore database -- you have to do so through the Firebase console. It's something we've heard requested many times and are looking at implementing in the future.

Comment: Ok... thanks for the quick response! Is there any public roadmap so I can see if this feature is being developed or will be developed in a near future?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Firebase doesn't comment publicly on timelines for upcoming features. The [Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) is a good place to go to see the latest news.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Firestore depends on an implementation of Google App Engine, I was able to programatically create a Firestore database using the Google App Engine api:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/api/appengine/v1"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
    "log"
)

// CreateFirestoreDatabase uses the Google App Engine API
// to create a Firestore database
func CreateFirestoreDatabase(ctx context.Context) error {
    
    // instantiate service
    service, err := appengine.NewService(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("appengine.NewService: %v", err)
    }
    
    // create application
    op, err := service.Apps.
        Create(&appengine.Application{
            DatabaseType: "CLOUD_FIRESTORE",
            Id:           "your-google-project-id",
            LocationId:   "europe-west",
        }).
        Context(ctx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return status.Errorf(
            codes.Internal,
            "service.Apps.Create: %s", err,
        )
    }
    
    // check the status of the longrunning operations
    // TODO: loop until op.Done == true
    _ = op
    
    return nil
}
```

The same process is used by the [gcloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/create):

```
gcloud firestore databases create [--region=REGION]
```

It is useful to have a look a the underlying python code backing the `gcloud` bin folder.  Here is a screenshot of the `gcloud firestore create` command confirming this:

[image: google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/firestore/create_util.py]

Answer (score 1):

The process can be automated using terraform and the work around to configure an [app engine application resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_application).

```
resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = "your-project-id"
  location_id = "us-central"
  database_type = "CLOUD_FIRESTORE"
}
```

As stated in the answers before firestore seems to rely on app engine even in the gcloud SDK.

Ugly but works.